# ON_EN_KILLFOCUS called multiple times

Tags: mfc, cedit

I am using a CEdit control. And I have assigned an event handler for ON_EN_KILLFOCUS message. It gets called correctly. But the problem is that, when ever, I close the dialog box, this event handler gets called four times. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why try to prevent it? Just make sure your handler ignores the ones that don't matter -

Comment: ok Jeff. I thought this was not a normal behavior. Is it the same case for all other UI controls?

Comment: Well, I have found it hard to predict when the controls will get called, so it's better to be prepared for anything, and just ignore messages if you need to -

Answer (score -1):

Just ran into similar issue and solved by separating to different handlers.

I was using:

```
ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(IDE_THRESHOLD, OnKillFocusOnEdit)
ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(IDE_AUTODENY_THRESHOLD, OnKillFocusOnEdit)
```

`OnKillFocusOnEdit` will receive two messages every time either of these two edits lose focus.

Now by changing to following, each function receives only one message as expected:

```
ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(IDE_THRESHOLD, OnKillFocusOnEdit)
ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(IDE_AUTODENY_THRESHOLD, OnKillFocusOnAutoDenyEdit)
```